# Django ModelForm for Many-to-Many fields

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Consider the following models and form:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ison = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, blank=True)

class ToppingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
```

When you view the ToppingForm it lets you choose what pizzas the toppings go on and everything is just dandy.

My questions is: How do I define a ModelForm for Pizza that lets me take advantage of the Many-to-Many relationship between Pizza and Topping and lets me choose what Toppings go on the Pizza?

Comment: So from your comments below:  Each `Pizza` can have many `Topping`s.  Each `Topping` can have many `Pizza`s.  But if I add a `Topping` to a `Pizza`, does that `Pizza` then automagically have a `Topping`, and vice versa?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I guess you would have here to add a new `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to your `PizzaForm`, and manually link that form field with the model field, as Django won't do that automatically for you.

The following snippet might be helpful :

```
class PizzaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza

    # Representing the many to many related field in Pizza
    toppings = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Topping.objects.all())

    # Overriding __init__ here allows us to provide initial
    # data for 'toppings' field
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only in case we build the form from an instance
        # (otherwise, 'toppings' list should be empty)
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            # We get the 'initial' keyword argument or initialize it
            # as a dict if it didn't exist.                
            initial = kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})
            # The widget for a ModelMultipleChoiceField expects
            # a list of primary key for the selected data.
            initial['toppings'] = [t.pk for t in kwargs['instance'].topping_set.all()]

        forms.ModelForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # Overriding save allows us to process the value of 'toppings' field    
    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Get the unsave Pizza instance
        instance = forms.ModelForm.save(self, False)

        # Prepare a 'save_m2m' method for the form,
        old_save_m2m = self.save_m2m
        def save_m2m():
           old_save_m2m()
           # This is where we actually link the pizza with toppings
           instance.topping_set.clear()
           instance.topping_set.add(*self.cleaned_data['toppings'])
        self.save_m2m = save_m2m

        # Do we need to save all changes now?
        if commit:
            instance.save()
            self.save_m2m()

        return instance
```

This `PizzaForm` can then be used everywhere, even in the admin :

```
# yourapp/admin.py
from django.contrib.admin import site, ModelAdmin
from yourapp.models import Pizza
from yourapp.forms import PizzaForm

class PizzaAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  form = PizzaForm

site.register(Pizza, PizzaAdmin)
```

#### Note

The `save()` method might be a bit too verbose, but you can simplify it if you don't need to support the `commit=False` situation, it will then be like that :

```
def save(self):
    instance = forms.ModelForm.save(self)
    instance.topping_set.clear()
    instance.topping_set.add(*self.cleaned_data['toppings'])
    return instance
```

Comment: This looks cool but I don't quite comprehend the code, esp the 'instance', save_m2m and old_save_m2m :)

Comment: @Viet: in django's documentation on forms (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), you can see that django automatically adds a `save_m2m` method to your `ModelForm` when you call `save(commit=False)` on it.

This is exactly what I'm doing here, adding a `save_m2m` method to save related objects and _toppings_, and this method calls the original `save_m2m`.

Comment: How is this solution better than Jack M.'s, i.e. introducing an intermediate model? This solution seems to require a lot more code.

Comment: Could this logic be reusable for any reverse M2M, using for example a mixin, a decorator, or something else?

Answer (score 17):

I'm not certain I get the question 100%, so I'm going to run with this assumption:

Each `Pizza` can have many `Topping`s. Each `Topping` can have many `Pizza`s. But if a `Topping` is added to a `Pizza`, that `Topping` then automagically will have a `Pizza`, and vice versa.

In this case, your best bet is a relationship table, which Django supports quite well.  It could look like this:

**models.py**

```
class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
    topping = models.ForeignKey('Topping')
    pizza = models.ForeignKey('Pizza')
class Pizza(models.Model):     
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    topped_by = models.ManyToManyField('Topping', through=PizzaTopping)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class Topping(models.Model):   
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_on = models.ManyToManyField('Pizza', through=PizzaTopping)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class PizzaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
class ToppingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topping
```

**Example:**

```
>>> p1 = Pizza(name="Monday")
>>> p1.save()
>>> p2 = Pizza(name="Tuesday")
>>> p2.save()
>>> t1 = Topping(name="Pepperoni")
>>> t1.save()
>>> t2 = Topping(name="Bacon")
>>> t2.save()
>>> PizzaTopping(pizza=p1, topping=t1).save() # Monday + Pepperoni
>>> PizzaTopping(pizza=p2, topping=t1).save() # Tuesday + Pepperoni
>>> PizzaTopping(pizza=p2, topping=t2).save() # Tuesday + Bacon

>>> tform = ToppingForm(instance=t2) # Bacon
>>> tform.as_table() # Should be on only Tuesday.
u'<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" value="Bacon" maxlength="50" /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_is_on">Is on:</label></th><td><select multiple="multiple" name="is_on" id="id_is_on">\n<option value="1">Monday</option>\n<option value="2" selected="selected">Tuesday</option>\n</select><br /> Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.</td></tr>'

>>> pform = PizzaForm(instance=p1) # Monday
>>> pform.as_table() # Should have only Pepperoni
u'<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" value="Monday" maxlength="50" /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_topped_by">Topped by:</label></th><td><select multiple="multiple" name="topped_by" id="id_topped_by">\n<option value="1" selected="selected">Pepperoni</option>\n<option value="2">Bacon</option>\n</select><br /> Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.</td></tr>'

>>> pform2 = PizzaForm(instance=p2) # Tuesday
>>> pform2.as_table() # Both Pepperoni and Bacon
u'<tr><th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" value="Tuesday" maxlength="50" /></td></tr>\n<tr><th><label for="id_topped_by">Topped by:</label></th><td><select multiple="multiple" name="topped_by" id="id_topped_by">\n<option value="1" selected="selected">Pepperoni</option>\n<option value="2" selected="selected">Bacon</option>\n</select><br /> Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.</td></tr>'
```

Comment: AttributeError at /requirements/add/
Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use requirements.AssetRequirement's Manager instead.

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I would put the many-to-many relation into the `Pizza` model. I think this closer to reality. Imagine a person that orders several pizzas. He wouldn't say "I would like cheese on pizza one and two and tomatoes on pizza one and three" but probably "One pizza with cheese, one pizza with cheese and tomatoes,...".

Of course it is possible to get the form working in your way but I would go with:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

Comment: The Pizza/Topping models are just a disguise for my real models.  The purpose of this question is because I want the Pizza ModelForm to let me choose Toppings and I want the Topping ModelForm to let me choose Pizzas.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way to achieve this is to create an intermediary table and using inline fields to get it done. Please refer to this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

Some sample code below

**models.py**

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ison = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza, through='PizzaTopping')

class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
```

**admin.py**

```
class PizzaToppingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PizzaTopping

class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PizzaToppingInline,]

class ToppingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PizzaToppingInline,]

admin.site.register(Pizza, PizzaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Topping, ToppingAdmin)
```

Comment: I assume that this takes effect only on admin pages/forms. How would you create similar for anonymous/guest users and/or logged in users to be able to post for example a pizza preference?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for, but are you aware that Pizza has the `topping_set` attribute?  Using that attribute you could easily add a new topping in your ModelForm.

```
new_pizza.topping_set.add(new_topping)
```

Answer (score 2):

We had similar problem in our app, which used django admin. There is many to many relation between users and groups and one can't easily add users to a group. I have created a [patch](http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/10964/group_admin.patch) for django, that does this, but there isn't much attention to it ;-) You can read it and try to apply similar solution to your pizza/topping problem. This way being inside a topping, you can easily add related pizzas or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar based in code of Clément with a user admin form:

```
# models.py
class Clinica(models.Model):
  ...
  users = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='clinicas')

# admin.py
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
  clinicas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Clinica.objects.all())

  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
      initial = kwargs.setdefault('initial',{})
      initial['clinicas'] = kwargs['instance'].clinicas.values_list('pk',flat=True)
    super(CustomUserChangeForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

  def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    instance = super(CustomUserChangeForm,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
    instance.clinicas = self.cleaned_data['clinicas']
    return instance

  class Meta:
    model = User

admin.site.unregister(User)

UserAdmin.fieldsets += ( (u'Clinicas', {'fields': ('clinicas',)}), )
UserAdmin.form = CustomUserChangeForm

admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a through table if you want to add stuff that is dependent on both primary keys of the table in the relationship. Many to many relationships use something called a bridge table to store stuff that is dependent on both parts of the primary key.

For example, consider the following relationship between Order and Product in models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_dights=7,decimal_places=2)
    qtyOnHand = models.Integer()
    orderLine = models.ManyToManyField(Order, through='OrderLine')

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    qtyOrd = models.Integer()
```

In your case, what you would do is put the ManyToMany on the Toppings, because it lets the user choose what toppings go on the Pizza they wanted. Simple, but powerful solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Django's [BaseInlineFormset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet).

You can create one easily using the [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.inlineformset_factory).

It is even possible to use the `ManyToManyField`'s [implicit through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), so you *do not* need to create an explicit `PizzaTopping` table yourself.

Here's a slightly modified version of the OP's example:

```py
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and here's how to create, and use, an inline formset for these models, e.g. in a view

```py
...
PizzaToppingFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    parent_model=Pizza, model=Pizza.toppings.through, fields='__all__')
...
pizza = Pizza.objects.get(...)  # however you get your pizza object
...
formset = PizzaToppingFormset(instance=pizza, data=request.POST)
...
```

For details on using these formsets in a view, check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view).

Note that the value of `formset.prefix` when using the `through` table would be `Pizza_toppings`, so your POST data would look like this, for example:

```py
data = {
    ...
    'Pizza_toppings-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
    'Pizza_toppings-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
    'Pizza_toppings-0-name': 'pepperoni',
    'Pizza_toppings-1-name': 'cheese',
    ...
}
```