# Django, set initial data to formset with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many

I need to set initial data to `formset` with `ManyToMany` field.

Usually i'm doing like this when there is *no* ManyToMany field in forms of my fomset:

```
PersonFormSet = forms.formsets.formset_factory(NickName, can_delete=True)
init_data = [{'name':'Vasya pupkin','nick':'Vasya'}, 
             {'name':'Vasyapupkin','nick':'Petya'}]

nick_formset = PersonFormSet(initial=init_data)
```

But now I need to set ManyToMany field initial data and tried something like this:

```
NickNameFormSet = forms.formsets.formset_factory(NickName, can_delete=True)
init_data = [{'name': 'Vasya Pupkin',
              'nick': {'Vasya':'selected',
                       'Petya':'notselected'}}]

nick_formset = NickNameFormSet(initial=init_data)
```

But it doesn't works.

How can I pass initial data to Formset so it render my widget like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="person_set-0-nickname" id="id_person_set-0-nickname">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Vasya</option>
    <option value="2">Petya</option>
</select>
```

**Note**: I'm using only Forms, and Formsets of Django. There is no Django models. I can actually define it but it's empty, I'm using `NoSQL`.

Comment: Actually i found solution. But it was more than one year ago. Dont remember it. I can look for it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a list of `pk` as initial data for your ManyToMany relation instead of a `dict`.

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields), it might helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__init__` function to pre-populate initial data.

Here's what I used for a similar problem:

```
class MyUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['real_supplements'] = [s.pk for s in list(self.instance.plan_supplements.all())]
```

Instead of using `self.instance.plan_supplements.all()` in my example, you can provide any Queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
class CustomFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = [
            {'foo_id': 1}
        ]
        super(CustomFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

the `foo_id` depends on the value that you're selecting for which field on the model relationship

You have to change also the `has_changed` method on the form class in order for the it to know that the initial values are "changed" to be taken in account when saved:

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def has_changed(self):
        """
        Overriding this, as the initial data passed to the form does not get noticed,
        and so does not get saved, unless it actually changes
        """
        changed_data = super(starnpc_class, self).has_changed()
        return bool(self.initial or changed_data)
```