# What's the cleanest way to add arbitrary data to ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-1.3, django-forms

Imagine we're developing a message system, and each `Message` has a foreign key for `sender`.

We're using `ModelForm`s, and there is a `MessageForm` that infers its fields from `Message`.
Of course, **we don't want the user to be able to spoof `sender` by posting a different sender ID**.

Therefore, we must exclude `sender` from `ModelForm` and fill it from `session` on post.

**Where and how should I assign arbitrary data to `ModelForm` fields?**

In my example, I probably want to access `session` so we need to access to `request` as well.
Does this mean the code has to be in the view, right after the form has been created?

How do we assign a form field from code and make sure it overrides POST data?

(Of course, the example is pretty fictional and is here just to illustrate the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just exclude it as you have and then when processing the form in the view do:

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.sender = request.user
obj.save()
```

Alternatively, you can do it in the save method of the form; for this you need to save the request object momentarily in the form. Something like the following:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self._request = request
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def save(self, commit=False):
    obj = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
    obj.sender = self._request.user
    if commit:
      obj.save()

    return obj
```

I prefer the second way myself as it helps encapsulate the logic regarding that model and it's data in one neat place.

Comment: That's a valuable addition, and I appreciate the samples. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what's the point of `commit=False` in this case?

Comment: @Dan Abramov: The `commit=False` is an argument you can pass to the `ModelForm.save()` method which will prevent the underlying model object from being saved. Instead the model is created (with the appropriate fields populated) and returned. Then you can set the other model fields and save the model.

Comment: There's a problem with this approach: calling `obj.save` does not persist m2m relationships. I think calling `form.save` instead works.

Comment: If you want to persist the m2m relations then you would have to do that separately yourself; you might want to take a look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude the `sender` field from the `ModelForm` and, when you instantiate the object in the view on the POST endpoint (just before saving), make sure you populate the `sender` field with the appropriate session or user ID.

When you exclude the field, there is no way to add the field to the post data[1], so a user can't spoof it.

[1] With JavaScript, a `&sender=someSenderId` could be added in theory, but in your view, you don't need to look for a sender field. It won't be serialized into the `ModelForm` object.

Comment: Coming from .NET background, I just failed to realize it can be *that* simple.