# How do I update Many to Many from both models?

Tags: python, django

Howdy I am trying to update a Many to Many field from both models. I can successfully update from the Cluster model the one with the M2M field, but I cant update it from the Subnet model.

What I will get in the template form for subnet is a list of clusters... buuuut

1. The clusters that are assigned to the subnet are not showing checked
2. When I do select a cluster and update the form it does not add the subnet to the cluster

Now im thinking I can only update the m2m relationship from the Cluster side, would I be right when I say that?

**models.py**

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    cluster = models.CharField(max_length=130, unique=True)
    subnet = models.ManyToManyField('Subnet', null=True, blank=True)

class Subnet(models.Model):
    network_address = models.IPAddressField()
    subnet_prefix = models.ForeignKey('SubnetPrefix')
```

**forms.py**

```
class SubnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cluster = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True, queryset=Cluster.objects.all())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div(Field('network_address', css_class="input-sm"), css_class="col-lg-4"),
            Div(Field('subnet_prefix', css_class="input-sm"), css_class="col-lg-2"),
            css_class="row"
        ),
        Div(
            Div(Field('cluster', css_class="nav nav-list"), css_class="col-lg-4"),
            css_class="row"
        ),
        Div(
            Div(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit'),
            ),
            css_class="row",
        ),
    )
    super(SubnetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Subnet
```

**views.py**

```
class SubnetUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'subnet_update.html'
    model = Subnet
    form_class = SubnetForm
    success_url = '#'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, u"Subnet updated successfully.")
        return super(SubnetUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**subnet_update.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Update Subnet</h1>
    <br />
        {% crispy form %}
    <br />
{% endblock %}
```

**html output of cluster form**

```
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-lg-4" >
<div id="div_id_cluster" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_cluster_0" class="control-label  requiredField">Cluster<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls " class="nav nav-list">
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="cluster" id="id_cluster_1" value="1"  class="nav nav-list">CLUSTER01</label>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="cluster" id="id_cluster_2" value="2" class="nav nav-list">CLUSTER02</label>
        <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="cluster" id="id_cluster_3" value="3"  class="nav nav-list">CLUSTER03</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code that really matters is no here. Where are the code you use to update models?

Comment: It's in my view SubnetUpdateView, after the form_valid method is called it is saved automatically. See ModelFormMixin via def form_valid(self, form): at http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of:

[Django ModelForm for Many-to-Many fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields)

The first answer doesn't change the models and shows you how to complicate your init and save methods to make your modelforms work.

The second answer keeps your forms simple by explicitly defining your own m2m through model.