# How do I represent two models on one page of form wizard?

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I'm struggling to figure out how best to approach this.

I have two models that need to be represented on one page within a form wizard:

```
class BookingItem(models.Model):
    assignedChildren = models.ManyToManyField('PlatformUserChildren', related_name = "childIDs", null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=2,blank=True, null=True)

class PlatformUserChildren(models.Model):
    child_firstname = models.CharField('Childs first name', max_length=30,blank=True, null=True)
```

The relationship between the models when presenting them on the page is NOT one-to-one. It is governed by quantity attribute and therefore there may be more BookingItems than PlatformUserChildren objects presented on the page (e.g. 4 BookingItems and 2 PlatformUserChildren objects). I loop through each object multiple times based on quantity.
I also need to bind to a queryset of the PlatformChildUser model based on the current logged in user.

**My question: how do I best present these two models on the first page of my form wizard?**

- I have looked at [inline_formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), but they rely on foreign key relationships only.
- I have tried a modelformset_factory for one model, and an additional identifier for the other model with some backend reconciliation later, but I'm stuck on how to get a queryset based on user in there
- i have attempted the [get_form_instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form_instance) method but I'm not 100% sure if it supports querysets
- finally, I have attempted overloading **init** however most of the examples are not based on form wizard, and supply external arguments.

My current (rather vanilla) code is below:

**forms.py**

```
class checkout_PlatformUserChildren(forms.ModelForm):
    #activity_id = forms.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = PlatformUserChildren
        fields = ('child_age','child_firstname')

    class Meta:
        model = PlatformUserChildren
        fields = ('child_age','child_firstname')
        widgets = {
            'child_firstname': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
            'child_age' : TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',}),
        }

checkout_PlatformUserChildrenFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        PlatformUserChildren, 
        form = checkout_PlatformUserChildren, 
        fields=('child_firstname', 'child_age'),
        extra=1, max_num=5, can_delete=True)
```

**views.py (done method not shown)**
note: getUser is an external function that is currently working

```
checkoutForms = [
    ("assign_child", checkout_PlatformUserChildrenFormSet),
    ("address_information", addressInfo),
        ]

checkoutTemplates = {
                "assign_child": "checkout/assign_child.html",
                "address_information": "checkout/address_information.html",
                }

class checkout(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        currentUser = getUser(self.request.user.id)
        if step == 'assign_child':
            self.instance = currentUser
        return self.instance
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields