# Django how to relate a foreign key object on form save

Tags: python, django

How can I create a relationship between my object and foreign key from a form submit? You can skip down to the very last line of code to see my issue.

### edit

My user will not have an option to select the related model object. The related model object will be exclusively the one identified by the `id` which is determined from the `URL`, i.e. `domain.com/myview/100`

`models.py`

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    activity = models.ManyToManyField(Activity, blank=True)
```

`forms.py`

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'John'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request, id=None):
    if id:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if contact_form.is_valid():
                contact = contact_form.save()
                # link contact to activity here, activity pk is 'id'
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need `id` field in the model, it's automatically generated. Django model is not relational database design.

Comment: @ShangWang What do you mean already in the form? Django may automatically create an ID, I can't remember. Shouldn't hurt to explicitly define it though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ModelForm for Many-to-Many fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216974/django-modelform-for-many-to-many-fields)

Comment: Sorry I misread your code, but I think it's been asked before. I'm just saying it's not necessary to have `id` as a field because django developers don't usually do that, just like python developers don't use `i` as index to loop a list.

Comment: @ShangWang My user will not have the option to select from model objects. The model to be linked is exclusively the `id`, which is access from the URL. I don't think my form will have a way to get a value from my URL.

Comment: @ShangWang that's right, I don't want to do that. The activity is already defined. Contacts will be added, and when they validate, they will be associated with the `activity` defined by the `id` of the `URL` from which they submitted the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally see what are you trying to do, it's pretty easy:

```
contact = contact_form.save()
# link contact to activity here, activity pk is 'id'
activity = Activity.objects.get(id=id)
contact.activity.add(activity)
```

I was confused before because you have `id` as view function parameter, which people usually use to update a `contact` because you also have a `ContactForm` in views.py method. You might make it more explicit using `activity_id` instead, and make the function name more explicit as well.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I forgot the syntax and it's always a pain to find these one-off things in the django docs, especially since I'm not on the latest version. Thank you for your patience.