# How to pass HyperLinkedModels to a form in Django with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have this serializer:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Project
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'project_id', 'user_set')
    read_only_fields = ('created', 'modified')
```

Then I have a form which is derived from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264722/7404090) answer. This is the code from it that I think is relevant:

```
user_set = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
```

You might already see the problem. The API expects `HyperLinkedModels` to be passed, but instead I pass plain `User` objects. So posting the form results in this error:

```
"user_set": [
    "Invalid hyperlink - No URL match."
]
```

I could edit the serializer to not expect a `HyperLink` but I would like to maintain that functionality. How can I parse the result from the queryset as `HyperLinkedModels`? Or how do I make it return `HyperLinkedModels` from the get go?

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: not sure but can you try with   (queryset=User.objects.all(), context={'request': request} )

Comment: @Vaibhav I don't think you can access the request in a form